# Decision in Puppet based on version of package installed

Tags: package, version, erb, puppet

I would like to do something like this in a Puppet .erb file:

```
<% if (version_of_apache_package_installed =~ /1.5.82/) then -%>
do one thing
<% else -%>
do a different thing 
<% end -%>
```

How do I put the version string of some installed package into the variable `version_of_apache_package_installed` so I can make the above work?

Answer (score 3):

Are you managing that apache [package resource in puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#package)? If so you can specify the version to install, so you'd just read from the same version variable in the package resource and in this if/else block.

In one of your init files ...

```
$package_version = '1.0'
```

in nodes ...

```
package { 'your_package':
  ensure => $package_version,
}
```

That's the right way to think in puppet, "make this machine be what I expect" not "I need to handle whatever this machine is".

You could use exec to handle the condition without managing the resource, but this isn't ideal at all.

Answer (score 2):

Puppet is a declarative language that makes sure that some resource (in this case package) is in required state. On each supported platform there might be different package manager following various conventions. Eventually some code could be executed when package state changes, e.g.:

```
<!-- language: puppet -->
package { "apache2":
  ensure => installed,
  notify => Exec['apache-updated']
}

exec { 'apache-updated'
  command => "/usr/bin/execute_some_script",
  refreshonly => true,
}
```

[According to documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/package.html#package-attribute-ensure) there are several special values for `ensure` attribute:

- `installed`
- `absent`
- specific version including patch version, e.g. `3.4.12-2` or `1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.3+deb9u5`
- etc.

You can obtain the current list of installed packages from CLI using:

```
puppet resource package
```

The motivation behind this is mostly performance. Checking package version is relatively fast, while execution of custom script will prolong `puppet agent` run time.

The best way how make decisions based on package version is to create a custom fact in some module `lib/facter/apache_version.rb`:

```
<!-- language: ruby -->
Facter.add(:apache_version) do
  setcode do
    if Facter::Util::Resolution.which('apache2')
      Facter::Util::Resolution.exec('apache2 -v | head -n 1 | awk  '{ print $3}' | cut -d "/" -f 2')
    end
  end
end
```

This way the versioning specifics should be handled for all supported OS. Then you can write in your code:

```
  <!-- language: puppet -->
  case $::apache_version {
    undef: {
      # during first run the version will be undefined, as the package is hasn't been installed yet
    }
    /^2/: {
      # TODO
    }
    default: {
      # TODO
    }
  }
```

In case you need to compare version, use [stdlib's](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib) function `versioncmp`:

```
if versioncmp($::apache_version, '2.0.0') < 0 {
    fail("foobar requires Apache 2.0 or greater, found: \'${::apache_version}\'")
}
```